# Override default Myth\Auth Route library in Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

need your help

i using Myth\Auth and want to seprating auth route for admin and front user cause there are different ways to login between both with different controller, but when i try to set in my config route like this :

```
$routes->group('', function($routes) {

    // Login/out
    $routes->get('login', 'AuthInformerController::login', ['as' => 'app-login']);
    $routes->post('login', 'AuthInformerController::attemptLogin');
    $routes->get('logout', 'AuthInformerController::logout');

    // Registration
    $routes->get('register', 'AuthInformerController::register', ['as' => 'app-register']);
    $routes->post('register', 'AuthInformerController::attemptRegister');

});
```

but this config not override default Route in \Myth\Auth\Config, How The way to override default route like this ?

[There is my Routes Files](https://github.com/masdikaid/e-services-disdukcapil/blob/auth/app/Config/Routes.php)

thanks for advice !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its will done with disable routes in config/modules.php :

```
public $aliases = [
        'events',
        'filters',
        'registrars',
        'routes',
        'services',
    ];
```

comment 'routes' in array make routes for all module not be autoload anymore, so you can manually define in your own routes.

```
public $aliases = [
        'events',
        'filters',
        'registrars',
        //'routes',
        'services',
    ];
```